# What is the difference between twitter photo card and summary with large image card?

Tags: twitter, twitter-card

I am trying to choose the right twitter card for our website. We serve interactive images so card should give a [static] preview of it + description and.. both summary card with large image and photo card seem to be identical :/

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/large-image-summary-card
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/types/photo-card

The only differences I can see is that for a photo card you are able to set dimensions in advance and have no title for the image, otherwise the cards seem to be identical.

What is the real difference between these card types?

P.S.
Example interactive image of ours to provide context - http://www.thinglink.com/scene/425660944702504962

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between a summary_large_image card and a photo card is what occurs when the user clicks on the image in the card:

- In the case of a summary_large_image card, a click on the image opens the link in a new tab (or in a browser on smartphones).
- In the case of a photo card, a click on the image opens a bigger version of the image in the same browser window (or displays the image full-screen on smartphones).